# ElasticSearch How to AND a nested query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to figure out how to AND my Elastic Search query. I've tried a few different variations but I am always hitting a parser error.

What I have is a structure like this:

```
{
  "title": "my title",
  "details": [
    { "name": "one", "value": 100 },
    { "name": "two", "value": 21 }
  ]
}
```

I have defined `details` as a nested type in my mappings. What I'm trying to achieve is a query where it matches a part of the title and it matches various details by the detail's `name` and `value`.

I have the following query which gets me nearly there but I haven't been able to figure out how to `AND` the details. As an example I'd like to find anything that has:

1. detail of **one** with value less than or equal to **100**
2. AND detail of **two** with value less than or equal to **25**

The following query only allows me to search by one detail name/value:

```
"query" : {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      { "match": {"title": {"query": titleQuery, "operator": "and" } } },
      {
        "nested": {
          "path": "details",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                { "match": {"details.name" : "one"} },
                { "range": {"details.value" : { "lte": 100 } } }
              ]
            }
          }
        } // nested
      }
    ] // must
  }
}
```

As a second question, would it be better to query the title and then move the nested part of the query into a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close! Just add another `"nested"` clause in your outer `"must"`:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "match": {
                  "title": {
                     "query": "title",
                     "operator": "and"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "details",
                  "query": {
                     "bool": {
                        "must": [
                           {"match": {"details.name": "one" } },
                           { "range": { "details.value": { "lte": 100 } } }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "details",
                  "query": {
                     "bool": {
                        "must": [
                           {"match": {"details.name": "two" } },
                           { "range": { "details.value": { "lte": 25 } } }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/1fc30d49a810d22e85fa68d781114c2865a7c92e

**EDIT:** Oh, the answer to your second question is "yes", though if you're using 2.0 things have [changed a little](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html#breaking_20_query_dsl_changes).